# Search If List Items are in Table

Tags: python

I am trying to find out if rps_amount_formatted is not in bpo_results_formatted and printing out some statement. However, not only is it duplicating a ton of times but the "not in" isn't working either. Its printing all the results no matter what I try to filter out for.

rps_table_amount_l

```
'1379535.8900','143514.1900','6592697.4000','2253675.3600'
```

bpo_results:

```
('2020/12/17   17:38:44', '1234', 'Copmany1', '1234', 'File1', '25000', '6,592,697.40', 'FILE RECEIVED', 'FPL', '2020-12-18 12:59:12.959827')
('2020/12/17   17:38:35', '1234', 'Copmany1', '1234', 'File2', '2003', '2,253,675.36', 'FILE RECEIVED', 'FPL', '2020-12-18 12:59:13.015895')
('2020/12/17   14:51:09', '1234', 'Copmany2', '1234', 'File3', '988', '143,514.19', 'FILE RECEIVED', 'FCG', '2020-12-18 12:59:13.019896')
('2020/12/17   14:30:37', '1234', 'Copmany3', '1234', 'File4', '2139', '1,379,535.89', 'ACCEPTED-NO ADJ', 'GP', '2020-12-18 12:59:13.024831')
```

results:

```
1379535.89 is not an amount received
1379535.89 is not an amount received
1379535.89 is not an amount received
143514.19 is not an amount received
143514.19 is not an amount received
143514.19 is not an amount received
6592697.40 is not an amount received
6592697.40 is not an amount received
2253675.36 is not an amount received
2253675.36 is not an amount received
```

code:

```
rps_table_amount_l = []

rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from test2 where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%I%' """
rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()

bpo_icl_awk_q_2 = f"""select * from test where receipt_date like '%{cd}%' """
postgres_cursor.execute(bpo_icl_awk_q_2)
bpo_table_results = postgres_cursor.fetchall()

for row in rps_table_results:
    rps_table_amount_l.append(row[18])

for rps_amount in rps_table_amount_l:
    for bpo_results in bpo_table_results:
        rps_amount_formatted = str(rps_amount)[:-2]
        bpo_results_formatted = str(bpo_results[6]).replace(',','')
        print(rps_amount_formatted)
        print(bpo_results_formatted)
        if rps_amount_formatted not in bpo_results_formatted:
            # print(rps_amount_formatted +" is not an amount recieved by a Bank Of America acknowledgement")
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this one.

```
rps_table_amount_l = []

rps_table_q_2 = f"""select * from test2 where processingdate = '{cd}' and datasetname like '%I%' """
rps_table_results = sql_server_cursor.execute(rps_table_q_2).fetchall()

bpo_icl_awk_q_2 = f"""select * from test where receipt_date like '%{cd}%' """
postgres_cursor.execute(bpo_icl_awk_q_2)
bpo_table_results = postgres_cursor.fetchall()

for row in rps_table_results:
    rps_table_amount_l.append(row[18])

get_rps_amount = [str(x)[:-2] for x in rps_table_amount_l]
get_table_amount = [str(x[6]).replace(',','') for x in bpo_table_results]

for rps in get_rps_amount:
    if rps in get_table_amount:
        print(bpo_table_results[get_table_amount.index(rps)][6])
```